# How do I disable automatic app switching?

Tags: macos, window-manager

I recently encountered this scenario: I had Evernote open, and it was updating itself. When I clicked "Update and Relaunch", I immediately switched back to Ommwriter. What I didn't expect was that upon relaunching Evernote, Mac OS would automatically switch to Evernote's window. The microsecond distraction was quite irritating.

I remember this being a distinctive pet peeve of my time using Windows, and in the early days of Mac OS, this wasn't an issue at all. It cropped up in some version that I can't remember... Is there a way to disable this auto-context-switching behaviour?

Comment: How should macOS know that Evernote (or any other application) will relaunch immediately after quitting?